# Can I use lambda:invoke to call AWS Lambda express app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, lambda, invoke

I have AWS Lambda express app which runs several endpoints

I want to invoke this app without api-gateway i.e. through lambda:invoke, but not able to figure out how to navigate to specific endpoints.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, its possible, but would have to provide IAM user or role credentials to the app itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly possible, that's exactly what the API Gateway is doing.

The application which you intend to request your Express Lambda directly will have to

So, assuming you have local credentials and your local user has permission to invoke your lambda function, you can do a simple test locally by doing this:

payload.json

```
{
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "path": "/PATH/TO/YOUR/ROUTE",
  "headers": { "content-type": "text/plain" },
  "body": "{\"version\":\"2.1.0\"}",
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

lambda-caller.js

```js
const region = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-west-2'
const lambda = new (require('aws-sdk/clients/lambda'))({ region })

const Payload = require('fs').readFileSync('payload.json')
const FunctionName = 'your-function-name'

lambda.invoke({ Payload, FunctionName }).promise().then(console.log)
```

Then just call your node app

```sh
node lambda-caller.js
```

That should print something like this

```js
{
  StatusCode: 200,
  ExecutedVersion: '$LATEST',
  Payload: '{"statusCode":202,"body":"{\\"count\\":1,\\"success\\":1}","headers":{"content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"23","date":"Thu, 21 May 2020 00:29:33 GMT","connection":"keep-alive"},"isBase64Encoded":false}'
}
```

Comment: hello, I followed this example and did get my lambda to call an endpoint on another express lambda, However, the payload doesn't seem to be available to the endpoint.
any idea that payload could be passed in?

so far, the information i found all pointed me back to calling via API gateway.

Thank you!

Comment: @Chuck did you make sure the body within the payload is json stringified ? you will need to Payload: JSON.stringify(payload) where in payload you also need to JSON.stringify(body)

Comment: sorry, i just see this message now. My partners and I decided to park this for now. We decided to use ApiGateway to get things working first and then come back to this a bit later. Thanks for your help!